# Semaphore value initialized to -1?

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore

I am trying to initialize a binary semaphore for some shared memory.  I could not figure out why I hung on a semop to get the semaphore, and eventually found that the semaphore value was -1 and I was stuck waiting.  What I don't get is why the semaphore value is initializing to -1 to begin with.  Any help clarifying this would be greatly appreciated.

```
semID = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); // create sem
int semval = semctl(semID, 1,GETVAL);

printf("After init Semaphore value = %d \n", semval);
printf("sem ID = %d \n", semID);
```

Output :

```
 After init semaphore value = -1 
 sem ID = 524304
```

Comment: RTFM: "On failure, semctl() returns -1 with errno indicating the error."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two bugs.  Your first bug is that, as always in C, the array of semaphores created by `semget` is 0-indexed; so, if you create only one semaphore, the second argument to `semctl` with that `semid` should be 0, not 1.  The -1 you're getting back from `semctl` is not the value of the semaphore, but an error indication (you should find that `errno == EINVAL`).

Your second bug is more subtle.  [The POSIX.1-2008 specification for `semget`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semget.html) says:

> Upon creation, ...
>
> - *the data structure associated with each semaphore in the set need not be initialized*. The [`semctl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semctl.html) function with the command `SETVAL` or `SETALL` can be used to initialize each semaphore.

(emphasis mine) What that means is, your code cannot rely on a new SysV semaphore having *any* specific value when it's first created.  You have to do something like this:

```
semID = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
if (semID < 0) {
    perror("semget");
    return -1;
}

union semun arg;
arg.val = 0;
if (semctl(semID, 0, SETVAL, arg) == -1) {
    perror("semctl");
    return -1;
}

// only now is it safe to use the semaphore
```

Note that you have to copy the definition of `union semun` out of the documentation into your code; it is not provided by any header.

If you're starting to get the feeling that this API is terrible, you are 100% correct.  You may find the [`semaphore.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/semaphore.h.html) API more congenial, however it *is* less widespread.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the [man page for semctl](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semctl) tells you that a return value of -1 means there was an error.

To get the error use [strerror](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) `printf( "%s", strerror(errno) );`

Don't forget `#include <errno.h>` and `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Should have known to be suspicious of a -1... doh... Thanks